# Add rows to a table then loop back and add more rows for a different userid

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, insert

I have a table with 4 columns - ID, ClubID, FitnessTestNameID and DisplayName
I have another table called Club and it has ID and Name

I want to add two rows of data to the 1st table for each club

I can write a statement like this, but can someone tell me how to create a loop so that I can insert the two rows, set the `@clubid + 1` and then loop back again?

```
declare @clubid int
set @clubid = 1

insert FitnessTestsByClub (ClubID,FitnessTestNameID,DisplayName)
values (@clubid,'1','Height (cm)')

insert FitnessTestsByClub (ClubID,FitnessTestNameID,DisplayName)
values (@clubid,'2','Weight (kg)')
```

Comment: Why did you change the tags? Add the platform that you're using

Comment: Post the tables' `CREATE` statements. Are some columns `IDENTITY`?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this with one statement only. No need for loops:

```
INSERT INTO FitnessTestsByClub 
    (ClubID, FitnessTestNameID, DisplayName)
SELECT
    c.ID, v.FitnessTestNameID, v.DisplayName
FROM
    Club AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES
        (1, 'Height (cm)'),
        (2, 'Weight (kg)') 
    ) AS v (FitnessTestNameID, DisplayName)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS                             -- a condition so no duplicates
    ( SELECT *                             -- are inserted
      FROM FitnessTestsByClub AS f         -- and the statement can be run again
      WHERE f.ClubID = c.ID                -- in the future, when more clubs
    )                                      -- have been added.
  ;
```

The **[Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)** syntax above (the `(VALUES ...)` construction) is valid from version 2008 and later.

There is a nice article with lots of useful examples of how to use them, by Robert Sheldon: **[Table Value Constructors in SQL Server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)**

Comment: You are assuming he doesn't want to add this for future clubs not yet in the club table and that he will run this when a new clubs is added with some sort of "if these don't already exist" logic

Comment: @jimdrang No, I'm not. When clubs are added in the future, in the `Club` table, the statement (slightly changed) can insert again 2 rows per club.

Comment: You either assume he doesn't want to or you assume he will know how to alter this/come up with another method for dealing with future clubs.

Comment: @jimdrang What are you talking about? I'm only assuming he wants to do what he describes in the question.

Comment: I think you should reread the question then unless it has changed and is not updating for me "can someone tell me how to create a loop so that I can insert the two rows, set the @clubid + 1 and then loop back again?

Comment: @jimdrang I've edited my answer. Is it ok now? It will work in the future, too, or if it is run twice (by accident.)